# Why does MACUSA think Goldstein helped Newt?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

Lord Graves says to Newt:

> Lord Graves: Miss Goldstein, who has aided and abetted you...

[image]

Here is the picture of Goldstein in prison.

Comment: What information does the image provide?

Comment: It probably gets the question past the "Low Quality due to _length_ and content" filter, @Shreedhar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Her contribution to his crime was detailed in an earlier scene.

> **TINA:** *Ma’am. Yesterday a wizard entered New York with a case. This case of magical creatures, and – unfortunately – some have escaped.*
>
> **MADAM PICQUERY:** *He arrived yesterday? **You have known for twenty-four hours that an unregistered wizard set magical beasts loose
> in New York and you see fit to tell us only when a man has been
> killed?***
>
> **TINA:** *Who has been killed?*
>
> **MADAM PICQUERY:** *Where is this man?*
>
> TINA sets the case flat on the floor and thumps the lid. After a
> second or two, it creaks open. First NEWT, then JACOB emerge, looking
> sheepish and nervous.

So, she didn't tell MACUSA about his presence and she was found to have been harbouring him.